# Installing git-lfs from source using go - cannot find package

Tags: git, go, git-lfs

I am trying to install git-lfs on an arm-based ubuntu machine. Package doesn't seem to exist so I need to install from source.

Seems like the installation depends on the go language so I installed it

```
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```

`go version` gives me: `go1.2.1 linux/arm`

Now I need to build git-lfs

```
go build ./src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs
```

and I get:

> cannot find package "context" in any of Same for `net/http/httptrace`

Other packages seem to have been found since I have set the path (after some fumbling around and setting a bunch of go environments params).

Now I see I can install more packages using `go get` , but it requires the full path, so I would need to know what is the fully qualified path to those two packages.

Is there a way to look up what is the full path for those packages? i.e. something equivalent to the py-pi in Python etc?

Comment: Go 1.2 is 5 years old... upgrade to 1.9

Comment: 1.9 is outdated too. Update to 1.10.1. Find a tarball at https://golang.org/dl/.

Comment: @Peter: Not true. Go supports the last two versions: "Each major Go release is supported until there are two newer major releases. Go 1.9 is supported until Go 1.11 is released." [Go Release Policy](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html#policy)

Comment: @peterSO, perhaps outdated was the wrong term. But advising to install a version that is not the most recent seems wrong to me.

Comment: @Peter: In production environments, it is common to run one or more versions behind, waiting for others to hopefully shake out any remaining bugs. In operating systems, Long Term Support (LTS) versions are commonly used for production: [Ubuntu LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS). I use `devel` and test on the two most recently released versions.

Answer (score 0):

[`Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) was supported only in [Go 1.7/1.8](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#more_context)

You need to add the right archive, as explained in the [Ubuntu page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gophers/archive
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install golang-1.10-go
```